# How to use -stream_loop audio in fluent-ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm trying to loop the audio to fit the size of the video. I use VIDEOSHOW to create VIDEO and videoshow uses fluent-ffmpeg.
I already have this code on the command line that works perfectly:

```
    `ffmpeg -y -r 1 -loop 1 -i image.png -stream_loop -1 -i audio.mp3 -c:a copy -r 1 
-shortest -c:v libx264 -t 60 -vf scale=1280:720 video.mp4
```

but I don't know how to use it with node-fluent-ffmpeg, here's the code I use:

```
 async function nodeFluentFfmpeg() {
    let image = [image.png]

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const videoOptions = {
      fps: 30,
      loop: segundoVideo, // seconds
      transition: true,
      transitionDuration: 1, // seconds
      videoBitrate: 1024,
      videoCodec: "libx264",
      size: "1280x720",
      audioBitrate: "128k",
      audioChannels: 2,
      format: "mp4",
      pixelFormat: "yuv420p"
      }

    videoshow(image, videoOptions)
      .audio("audio.mp3","**-stream_loop -1 -c:a copy -r 1**")// **ERROR IS HERE**
      .save("video.mp4")
      .on("start", function(command) {
        console.log("Rendering : ", command);
      })
      .on("error", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.error("Error:", err);
        console.error("ffmpeg stderr:", stderr);
      })
      .on("end", function(output) {
        console.error("Video created in:", output);
        resolve()
      });

    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve with `.inputOption(`-stream_loop -1`);` .